# Mysql query option param

Tags: php, mysql

There is my query string, are there any problems about the bindParam?

```
$str = "select A.option_id,count(*) as sum 
            from tb_feedback A,tb_question B,tb_group C 
            where (A.question_id=B.id) 
            and (:question is null or B.id=:question) 
            and (B.group_num=C.id) 
            and (:group is null or C.name=:group) 
            and (:fromdate is null or A.date >= CAST(:fromdate AS DATE)) 
            and (:todate is null or A.date <= CAST(:todate AS DATE)) 
            group by A.option_id";
        $sql = $this->conn->prepare($str);
        $sql->bindParam(':question', $obj['question']);
        $sql->bindParam(':group', $obj['group']);
        $sql->bindParam(':fromdate', $obj['fromdate']);
        $sql->bindParam(':todate', $obj['todate']);
```

Comment: Seems fine, why do u ask?

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Mureinik  yeah, seems fine, but run my program, it return null, and actually some record existing in my dasebase

Comment: do u have $sql->execute(); ?

Comment: @borik Please avoid using "text speak" as many people on Stack Overflow are not native English speakers and are unfamiliar with a lot of that shorthand.

Comment: Its hard to tell why you getting "0 NO RESPONSE", from the code you provided, without seeing full code.

Comment: @Borik its very strange, get return only when I pass 'fromdate' and 'todate ' this two param at same time.

Comment: Im sorry, not "0 NO RESPONSE", its my mistake,it due to server closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason that parameter's type not NULL, it is string, so it is not succeed when execute the next statement 
`(:question is null or B.id=:question)`

Comment: Please consider giving yourself a green checkmark if you consider your answer the right one.